# JS based NVD3 chart in java ee with jsf bad idea?

Tags: javascript, jsf, jakarta-ee

I want to implement a xhtml Page in my Java EE project, which will show data from a db. The chart I had an eye one was NVD3 charts, which is based on java script.

The implementation I had in mind was like this:

User can fill in textfields with a "from-date" and a "to-date" to set the date-range where data from the database should be collected. The collected data will then be marshalled into JSON format and the chart created based on the data. Here I somehow have to get the marshalled data from Java to the JS function.

I guess I could this get to work, I am quite a fan of the NVD3 charts but somehow this mixing of JavaEE with JSF and javascript seems bad practice to me.

I wanted to know if this is kind of a bad idea to do and what you would advise me to do here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"but somehow this mixing of JavaEE with JSF and javascript seems bad practice to me. "_ PrimeFaces, RichFaces, IceFaces etc all use javascript. PrimeFaces charts even use jqPlot, so it is perfectly fine. And did you find e.g. http://ramannanda.blogspot.nl/2014/05/nvd3-and-primefaces-better-charting.html?

Comment: Wow, this is really great! Thank you for sharing the link with me